# The undefined parameter property will be cleared away in the HTTP request payload

Tags: javascript, http

I add the `physicalserver_id` field to my parameter object (`params`), then send HTTP request:

```
var params =  this.entityServer
params.extra_desc = JSON.stringify(this.entityServer.extra_desc)
params.physicalserver_id = undefined

debugger // there I have checked the `params.physicalserver_id`

this.$http.post('/api/xxx/add/', params).then( (response) => {
    console.log(response, 'lml')
})
```

However, I get the error from backend, telling me that `physicalserver_id` field is required.

In my browser, I check the Request Payload:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and find there is no `physicalserver_id`.

if I give an existed number:

```
params.physicalserver_id = 8
```

Then, the problem disappeared.

[image]

---

**EDIT-1**

My question is, in my params I give the `physicalserver_id=undefined`, but when I request the API, the Request Payload do not exist the `physicalserver_id`, see my snapshot.

Comment: Better to `delete` properties from objects. But I don't understand your question, what exactly is the problem? Sounds like it might be an issue on the backend if the request is as expected?

Comment: Because you are setting it to `undefined`, `undefined` values do not get included/sent.

Comment: @PatrickEvans The original with this statement. now what should I set ?

Comment: It depends on the API what you need to set but you can try an empty string.

Comment: undefined and null value param will not sent to request ! Try `''` (empty) instead ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the behaviour of `JSON.stringify()`.

When you invoke `this.$http.post('/api/xxx/add/', params)`, the frontend system (I guess you are using Angular) will convert `params` to string via `JSON.stringify()`. As `params` is an object, all fields with `undefined` value would be omitted in the final result string. Thus, the `physicalserver_id` field would be missing in the request payload.

Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for detail description:

> If undefined, a Function, or a Symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

As @HMR commented, you need to check with API provider on "how to send empty physicalserver_id".

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, in the JavaScript undefined means nothingness.You set the parameters to not exist,the program will assume that there is no such parameter.In other words,the program can't find this parameter at all.So you must set a value for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, parameter with value of **undefined** wasn't being passed to backend api but with value of **null**, it was successfully being passed to backend endpoint. Its because null is a valid value for databases as values can be **nullable** but **undefined** is not a valid value